# How will i use Crystal Reports on Executive Summary(and other summaries) & Letters?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, report

The system that we are going to develop in our capstone project needed printed reports like Summaries, Letters and Memos. i needed to know how to use crystal reports in C#.

Answer (score 0):

see a link.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10948/How-to-use-Crystal-Report-in-your-project
http://csharp.net-informations.com/crystal-reports/csharp-crystal-reports-tutorial.htm

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider alternatives as Crystal requires quite a bit of knowledge and "special" software. Not to mention the dependencies and issues surrounding.

Could you use word templates for example? Where placeholders are used and your application merges the data in according. This makes the reports 100x more maintainable by end users.

Comment: do you mean word templates such as word? or excel?

Comment: @penchii not .dot in that sense but yes, a word document with placeholders for merging data in

Comment: @penchii: If you are using the Microsoft "stack", have you considered reporting with SSRS instead of Crystal?

Comment: thanks for the responses, i really appreciate it. uhm im just thinking if how am i going to link my "system" to word documents? thank you so much in advance. im not really good at programming but really trying hard to learn. thank you again. in advance.

Comment: @ mark Bannister: uhm. what do you mean by microsoft "stack"? as far as i know, im using Visual studio 2008 C#. any my database is Mysql Database express. (.mdf). -im not really  good at programming and its terminologies. but of course really really eager to learn. thanks in advance. =)